# Mercurial Branch / File name completion in ZShell

Tags: mercurial, zsh, tab-completion

I've been using Zsh as a Bash replacement for a while now. One thing that doesn't work as well anymore is the completion for branch and uncommitted file names for mercurial.

If previously (bash) I had the following hg tracked folder:

```
repo/
    .hg/
    file1.txt
    file2.txt <-- modified
```

Then doing this in Bash:

```
% hg commit -m "changed file2.txt" <TAB>
```

automagically completed `file2.txt`.

Same with branches — assuming I had `default`, `dev` and `crazy` branches, Bash knew how to complete branch names:

```
% hg update cr<TAB>
```

completed the branch name to `crazy`.

Basically what I'm asking is how to restore this functionality — which file/s take care of that and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zsh` uses its internal system for advanced completion, while `bash` uses a separate `bash-completion` software for that. Their configuration is incompatible so if you want some function to work you need to find a 3rd party zsh completion module for it or write it yourself. `mercurial` contains a sample zsh completion function, it is installed on my system as `/usr/share/doc/mercurial/examples/zsh_completion.gz`.